# RxJava — emit on subscribeOn() thread

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
Single.create { emitter ->
   // I/O thread here

   ThirdPartySDK.doSomeAction {
       // Main thread here

      emitter.onSuccess(someValue)
   }
}
.flatMap {
  someOtherSingle(it) // Executes on main thread
}
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe({},{})
```

The `ThirdPartySDK.doSomeAction` callback posts on main thread, so the emitter will emit on the main thread too, not on the subscribe thread (and if I have some network interactions further in the `flatMap`, chain will fail).

If I add `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` after the first `Single`, it switches to the correct thread, but is there any way to emit on right thread? I can't modify `ThirdPartySDK` behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## subscribeOn

The subscribeActual lambda will be invoked on given scheduler

## observeOn

Switch thread to given scheduler. Every upstream-onNext call will be called from an ObserveOn-Scheduler-Thread

As you already said, subscribeOn will only invoke the subscribeActual method call on subscribe on given Scheduler-Thread. This does not mean, that the downstream emit will be on the same thread. In your case the onSuccess emit will be called from a different thread (e.g. Database/ Http-ThreadPool etc.).

onSuccess will be called from a unknown thread (in your case main thread). The downstream call will be called from the main-thread. Therefore flatMap is called from the main-thread. Network-calls on the main-thread in the flatMap will probably fail, because it is not allowed to "block" the main-thread.

How to solve this issue?
Just place a observeOn after the Single#create. The main-thread calls onSucess. The observeOn-subscriber will get called from the main-thread. The observeOn-subscriber re-directs onSuccess downstream-call (e.g. flatMap) to given ObserveOn-Scheduler-Thread. Therefore it is given, that flatMap is called from a non main-loop thread.

Example:

```
@Test
fun wurst() {
    val thirdPartySDKImpl = ThirdPartySDKImpl()
    Single.create<String> { emitter ->
        thirdPartySDKImpl.doSomeAction {
            emitter.onSuccess(it)
        }
    }
        // .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        // move emit from unknown thread to computation thread
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        // Single.just will be subscribe from a computation thread
        .flatMap { Single.just(123) }
        // move onSucess/ onError emit from computation thread to main-thread
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        // subscribe onNext / onError will be called from the main-android-thread
        .subscribe({}, {})
}

interface ThirdPartySDK {
    fun doSomeAction(callback: (v: String) -> Unit)
}

class ThirdPartySDKImpl : ThirdPartySDK {
    override fun doSomeAction(callback: (v: String) -> Unit) {
        // <- impl-detail ->
        callback("whatever")
    }

}
```

NOTE: You do not need a subscribeOn, if the create-lambda does not block or does some cpu heavy stuff. If it only subscribes to a callback, which will be called from a different thread, you do not need subscribeOn.

> but is there any way to emit on right thread?

You should not use any concurrency in operators. You would think, you could just do something like:

```
    Single.create<String> { emitter ->
        thirdPartySDKImpl.doSomeAction {
            Schedulers.io().scheduleDirect {
                emitter.onSuccess(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not recommended, because you could break the serialized onNext contract^1. This example would make sure, that the onSucess downstream call would happen on expected thread, but cancellation/ unsubscription is not handled and there might be other pitfalls.

If you have a non reactive API and you want to enforce some threading-model I would suggest to wrap the sync. API with an async one and provide proper observeOn/ subscribeOn operators. Later on only use the async API.

```
interface ThirdPartySDKAsync {
    fun doSomeAction(): Single<String>
}

class ThirdPartySDKAsyncImpl(private val sdk: ThirdPartySDK, private val scheduler: Scheduler) :
    ThirdPartySDKAsync {
    override fun doSomeAction(): Single<String> {
        return Single.create<String> { emitter ->
            sdk.doSomeAction {
                emitter.onSuccess(it)
            }
        }.observeOn(scheduler)
    }
}
```

Further reading: https://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html

^1 Only one thread a time is allowed to call onNext/onSuccess/onError/onComplete